# How to pull a API Response data into a HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

i'm trying to pull data from a response i'm getting on a Google Workspace API request to a HTML table, the response i'm getting is an array that is being store at an HTML element every time I made the request. Here's my code for it:

```
  function execute() {
     return gapi.client.directory.users.list({"domain": "mydomain", "maxResults": 450})
            .then(function(response) {
                let t = document.querySelector("#tabela") 
               let data = []    
                console.log(response)
                    response.result.users.forEach((user)=> {
                       
                        data.push(user) 
                        // console.log("Email"+ user.primaryEmail) 
                        // console.log("Email"+ user.lastLoginTime) 
                     SheetDB.write('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/81m3qdtu47hra', { sheet: 'Sheet1', data:  {email: '${user.primaryEmail}' , login: '${user.lastLoginTime}'}}).then(function(result){
                     console.log(result);
                    }, function(error){
                     console.log(error);
    });
                    })
                    console.log(data)
                    let td = data.reduce((acc, user)=>{
                      acc += `<tr>${user.lastLoginTime}</tr>`
              
                      return acc
                  },"")
                  t.innerHTML = td
                  console.log("O result é:", td)
                  },
                  function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });`
```

and then, my code which is not working to populate my html table with it:

```
     <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr  class="bg-info">
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Last Login Time</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Permissions</th>
        </tr>
    
        <tbody id="myTable">
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <script>
        var myArray = document.querySelector("#tabela")
        
        buildTable(myArray)
    
    
    
        function buildTable(data){
            var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
    
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                var row = `<tr>
                                <td>${user.primaryEmail}</td>
                          </tr>`
                table.innerHTML += row
    
    
            }
        }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `buildTable` function requires an array as the argument to the function whereas you are passing the entire `myTable` element as the argument on the second line in your script tag. That is why the for loop never gets executed since `data.length` would be undefined. Pass the array of data from the API to the function and you should be good to go.